# Clustered ActiveMQ Artemis and producer/consumer load balancing configuration when broker fails

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have created an ActiveMQ Artemis cluster with two active brokers. I have created a custom load balancer to be able to initially distribute my queues in a static way according to my requirements and workload.

```xml
<connectors>
  <connector name="broker1-connector">tcp://myhost1:61616</connector>
  <connector name="broker2-connector">tcp://myhost2:62616</connector>
</connectors>

<cluster-connections>
  <cluster-connection name="myhost1-cluster">
    <connector-ref>broker1-connector</connector-ref>
    <retry-interval>500</retry-interval>
    <use-duplicate-detection>true</use-duplicate-detection>
    <message-load-balancing>ON_DEMAND</message-load-balancing>
    <max-hops>1</max-hops>
    <static-connectors>
      <connector-ref>broker2-connector</connector-ref>
    </static-connectors>
  </cluster-connection>
</cluster-connections>
```

My issue is that when broker1 is down then based on this topology I can recreate its queues on broker2 to avoid losing messages (by using connection string on producer `(tcp://myhost1:61616,tcp://myhost2:62616)`).

But then when broker1 becomes available again my producer is unaware of that and it stills uses the connection to broker2 (if that matters broker2 `redistribution-delay` is set to 0 and no consumers are registered). Is there a way or some configuration to resume my producer to write only to broker1.

This affects my consumers which are initially connected to broker1, and I am not sure if there is also some way/configuration to make them transparently bounce between these brokers or do I need to create two consumers (effectively one them will be idle) each one targeting the corresponding broker ?

Comment: Have you conducted performance benchmarks to determine you actually need a cluster of 2 brokers?

Comment: Actually I am about to move on performance testing. My main issue is that I shall have a few hundred thousand messages (~1/4 million) scheduled for a point in time. I need to be able to cope with that as soon as possible and since I have 2 brokers available clustered solution seemed to be the safe approach

Comment: How do you know if the number of messages is actually an issue if you haven't tested yet? Also, the overall performance is more likely to be tied to the number of consumers and producers you have. ActiveMQ Artemis scales well with a large number of clients, but if you only have a couple of producers and consumers connected then that will be your performance bottleneck.

Comment: Also, it's not clear what you mean by "I shall have a few hundred thousand messages (~1/4 million) scheduled for a point in time." Does that mean the messages are already in the queue and are scheduled for delivery at a certain time? Does that mean a producer is scheduled to send those messages to a queue at a certain time? Also, what do you mean by "I need to be able to cope with that as soon as possible"? Are you saying you have a project dead-line you need to meet or that the messages need to be processed by the broker/clients as quickly as possible?

Comment: Ok my initial assumption was that if I can have two brokers I can scale easier my load. Having multiple consumers and producers on one node would had an impact on performance.

Comment: For what it's worth, a cluster's topology should generally be transparent to client applications. One of the goals of clustering is to be able to add & remove nodes dynamically as load ramps up and drops off. Tying clients to certain nodes in a cluster defeats that goal. You may consider a different architecture where clients don't really care what node they're connected to.

Comment: You *can* scale your load more easily with a cluster, but you also have to consider that there's additional complexity and cost to clustering so if you don't absolutely *need* to scale your load with clustering then it's best to avoid the additional complexity, etc. A single node can handle hundreds or potentially thousands of concurrent producers and consumers. General development guidelines recommend that first you make something work and *then* you make it fast. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/).

Comment: Ok thanks I understand your point, I'll move on to a HA policy and proceed with performance testing to confirm that it can cope with my load

Comment: Also, keep in mind that a message broker is not a database. It's not meant to *store* a lot of data. It's meant to be a broker *through which* a lot of data moves. If you dump a lot data on the broker with no consumers then performance will suffer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for the broker to tell a client that it should connect to another node joining the cluster.

My recommendation would be to use HA with failback so that when one node fails then all the clients connected to that node failover to the backup and then when the original node comes back all the clients failback to the original node.

You may also find that you don't actually *need* a cluster of 2 brokers. Many users never perform the performance testing necessary to confirm that clustering is even necessary in the first place. They simply assume that a cluster is necessary. Such an assumption can needlessly complicate a platform's architecture and waste valuable resources. The performance of ActiveMQ Artemis is quite good. A single node can handle millions of messages per second in certain use-cases.